# How do I within SQLite, return a row based on 3 values rather than just one? (Already done code for 1)

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

Within SQLite, I can search a table for a particular row which contains 1 values for instance a player name but I want to return a row based on 3 values for instance Player name, Team name and favorite color etc.

**How do I alter below code to do this?**

Code for searching based upon one value is below:

```
public BackupDatastore getentry(String value, String columnName) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_Name, 
                    new String[] { KEY_ID,
                                         KEY_Team_Name, 
                                 KEY_Ref_Name, 
                                 KEY_Date, 
                                 KEY_Player_1,
                                 KEY_Player_2,
                                 KEY_Player_3,
                                 KEY_Player_4,
                                 KEY_Player_5,
                                 KEY_Player_6,
                                 KEY_Player_7 ,
                                 KEY_Player_8},
                    columnName + "=?",
                            new String[] { value }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
{
        boolean move = cursor.moveToFirst();
    //false value means the query returned 0 results
    if(!move) 
    {
    return BackupDatastore.kEmptyData;
     }
}

    BackupDatastore entry = new BackupDatastore(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),  cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11));
    // return entry
    return entry;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could youse arrayList and using hash map temporary add values in list<?>. then display them through listview or something.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change what you're passing as the 3rd and 4th parameters - the column names and values passed to the WHERE clause.

For example, to filter across 3 columns you'd do:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_Name, 
                new String[] { KEY_ID,
                                     KEY_Team_Name, 
                             KEY_Ref_Name, 
                             KEY_Date, 
                             KEY_Player_1,
                             KEY_Player_2,
                             KEY_Player_3,
                             KEY_Player_4,
                             KEY_Player_5,
                             KEY_Player_6,
                             KEY_Player_7 ,
                             KEY_Player_8},
                column1Name + "=? AND " +
                column2Name + "=? AND " +
                column3Name + "=? ",
                        new String[] { value1, value2, value3 }, null, null, null, null);
```

This will build an expression similar to `SELECT Player1, Player2, ... FROM TeamName WHERE FirstName = 'X' AND LastName = 'Y' AND TeamName = 'Z'`

You could build this dynamically using variable length args, or passing in string arrays, rather than simply a method defined to take 3 columns & 3 values as parameters, for example:

```
public BackupDatastore getentry(String[] values, String[] columns) {
    if (values.length != columns.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of columns does not match number of values provided.");
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        sb.append(columns[i]);
        sb.append("=?");
        if (i != columns.length - 1) {
            sb.append(" AND ");
        }
    }
    String whereColumns = sb.toString();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_Name, 
                new String[] { KEY_ID,
                                     KEY_Team_Name, 
                             KEY_Ref_Name, 
                             KEY_Date, 
                             KEY_Player_1,
                             KEY_Player_2,
                             KEY_Player_3,
                             KEY_Player_4,
                             KEY_Player_5,
                             KEY_Player_6,
                             KEY_Player_7 ,
                             KEY_Player_8},
                whereColumns,
                values, null, null, null, null);
    ...
```

Comment: Get the error:
The method query(String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String, String) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, String[], String, String, String, String[], null, null, null, null)

Comment: Yeah my original post had commas between the different columns in the where filter rather than plus-signs, resulting in 3 strings being passed not 1. Try the new code, or even try the new method I wrote up, it's much more generic.